# Adding of Count in Excel

Tags: excel

How do I increment the row count (`Cnt`) based on the Number column in Excel? Are there any formulas that I can use to generate the `Cnt` column?

```
Cnt  Number
1    IF1234
1    IF1234
2    IF4444
2    IF4444
3    IF5555
3    IF5555
```

Comment: Question isn't exactly clear. Where are you getting the count from?

Comment: Are you saying, for example, the value IF4444 implies Cnt=2? If not, why is Cnt=2 the expected value on those rows? If we knew why Cnt is supposed to be 2 here, we might be able to tell you if Excel can do that.

Comment: Hi, The 'Number' field is is a list of records that I have generated from some database but I need to compute the 'Cnt' field one . Row 1 and Row 2 are with the same Number values so I have to set Cnt as 1 , Row 3 and 4 are another set of same Number values so I have to increment the Cnt to 2 and so on. I am not sure how to increment the 'Cnt' if the 'Number' fields are the same.

Answer (score 2):

If the values in the Number column are sorted (i.e., grouped), you can do the following.

1. Enter "1" in A2 (the first Cnt value).
2. Enter `=IF(B3=B2,A2,A2+1)` in A3, where column B holds the Number values.
3. Fill down the formula in A3.

If, however, the values in the Number column are **NOT sorted**, you will need to do the following:

1. Enter "1" in A2.
2. Enter `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,B$2:B2,0)),MAX(A$2:A2)+1,INDEX(A$2:A2,MATCH(B3,B$2:B2,0)))` in A3.
3. Fill down the formula in A3.